# AngularJS $http object not showing all headers from response

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm having a problem with AngularJS's $http service not returning all of the headers from the API I'm polling. Here's what I've got:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: true,
    url: 'http://api.mydomain.com/query',
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    ... // setting some scope parameters based on data
    console.log(headers());
})
```

I can tell through the network tab in Chrome that a bunch of response headers are being returned by the API (I'm particularly interested in the X-Pagination-Total-Items header).

Here's a screenshot of the network tab from the request:
[image: Chrome's Network Panel]

But the console.log statement above (which should output all headers) only returns two:
[image: Console Log...missing headers!]

Any idea what's going on? How do I actually access all of the headers coming back from the AJAX call?

Thanks,

-Nate

Comment: Which headers can't you access? (Also, consider prepending them with `X-`)

Comment: Benjamin, I'm trying to get X-Pagination-Total-Items. I'm wondering if it's a CORS issue and whether Access-Control-Expose-Headers can't take a wildcard...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Turns out that the Access-Control-Expose-Headers cannot accept a wildcard. We needed to specify exactly which headers the client should have access to, and then it worked.

Comment: I spent HOURS trying to figure this out. Thank you, thank you, a million times thank you

Comment: @EliGassert, glad it helped you as well. One of the great things about StackOverflow! :-)

Comment: Oh my god.. I too forgot to add these headers to my CORS filter. No wonder I could see them in the browser response but not in the AngularJS headers() call output.

Comment: Is this on the backend issue?

Comment: Yes, this is a backend issue.  You should configure your web server to send back desired header fields.

Wildcards are not supported so this won't work;
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*`

Instead you should provide exact header field i.e.
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Etag`

Comment: If you come from google: on apache2 you need to enable the `headers` module

Comment: It is stated pretty clearly in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers that you cannot use * for requests with HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information

Comment: @NathanRutman You should accept your own answer as no one else can mark as solution...